# loading profile image of G+ and Facebook in android app while offline

Tags: android

In my android app I implemented `NavigationView` header with circular profile image loaded from `Facebook/Google Plus`. But Navigation header shows image with internet connection.

I want to show the image in offline mode also. Can anyone tell me the possible way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Save the image to disk? Or use Volley ImageLoader or Picasso to cache it

Comment: Use _Glide_ or _Picasso_ which provide cache _strategy_

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes. this works for me. I used Picasso and it is working fine. Please write it as answer of this post, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @codehub Posted answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For caching , there are good libraries are available.... you can use *Picasso* or *Glide* which provides caching strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Use Volley, is a recommended library from Android to make request. It also have the ImageCache function.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) there is a goof tutorial.

Hope it helps.